# Why doesn't a question with score of 5 show up in Top Questions in my network profile?

Tags: support, questions, profile-page

I've asked [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1115643/search-for-files-with-a-specific-file-extension-in-windows-7) and it has a score of 5 (it's my only question with score of 5 or more on the Stack Exchange). But in [my network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/5378624/donald-duck), there is a part called "Top  Questions" where it says "No questions with score of 5 or more". This isn't correct since the question for which I posted the link has a score of 5. At the beginning, I thought that it might be because the person who  voted it up had a grace period and could cancel the up voting, but now this has been the case for several weeks and the question still hasn't shown up on my network profile. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is currently closed as a duplicate. According to [this MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254477/295684), the post must have a score of at least 5 (you have this), not be community wiki (check), and not be closed even as a duplicate.

Note that *answers* to closed questions still appear in the Top Answers section as long as they're non-wiki and scored at least 5.